# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'dlfcn.h': No such file or directory PyLPSolve

Tags: python, python-2.7, lpsolve

**[CLOSED]** I'm trying install pylpsolve using python 2.7 on windows 10, 64 bits. When I run `python setup.py install` I've the following error: `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'dlfcn.h': No such file or directory`.
I have searched the web (specifically [here](http://lp-solve.2324885.n4.nabble.com/fatal-error-C1083-Cannot-open-include-file-dlfcn-h-td7319.html) and [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mathematics.lpsolve/8781)) and can not find solution. I hope you can help me.

Comment: A simple Google search for [`dlfcn.h`](https://www.google.com/#q=dlfcn.h) turned up [this](https://github.com/dlfcn-win32/dlfcn-win32). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah, but i don't know where paste the dlfcn.h file.

Comment: It'll be properly installed when you compile the repo. Sorry, I'm not on Windows, so I can't say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should note that `pylpsolve` seems to be pretty much dead.  It never supported Windows, seems to have a lot of outstanding pull requests, and in my testing seems to have some bugs.

On the other hand, you may be able to make use of it and it is not too difficult to fix your problem. You are getting the message because the `setup.py` is essentially re-compiling `lpsolve` and in the process, doing it for linux not Windows.  The `setup.py` might work properly as is on linux but on windows you'll need to make a few changes.

I think the key changes are to add these values to the compiler arguments in setup.py:

```
"-D_WINDLL", "-DWIN32"
```

I have got a successful compile using the following lines in my `setup.py`.

```
lpsolve_base = 'lp_solve_5.5'

compiler_args = ["/Gz", "/Zp8", "-D_WINDLL", "-DWIN32", "-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE",
                 "-D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE", "-DYY_NEVER_INTERACTIVE", "-DPARSER_LP",
                 "-DINVERSE_ACTIVE=INVERSE_LUSOL", "-DRoleIsExternalInvEngine"]

extensions = [
    Extension("pylpsolve",
    include_dirs = [os.path.join(lpsolve_base, d) for d in ['.',
                    'shared', 'bfp', 'bfp/bfp_LUSOL', 'bfp/bfp_LUSOL/LUSOL',
                    'colamd']] + [numpy.get_include()],
    sources = ["pylpsolve.pyx"] + [os.path.join(lpsolve_base, f) for f in
                ['lp_MDO.c', 'shared/commonlib.c', 'shared/mmio.c', 'shared/myblas.c',
                 'ini.c', 'fortify.c', 'colamd/colamd.c', 'lp_rlp.c', 'lp_crash.c',
                 'bfp/bfp_LUSOL/lp_LUSOL.c', 'bfp/bfp_LUSOL/LUSOL/lusol.c', 'lp_Hash.c',
                 'lp_lib.c', 'lp_wlp.c', 'lp_matrix.c', 'lp_mipbb.c', 'lp_MPS.c', 'lp_params.c',
                 'lp_presolve.c', 'lp_price.c', 'lp_pricePSE.c', 'lp_report.c', 'lp_scale.c',
                 'lp_simplex.c', 'lp_SOS.c', 'lp_utils.c', 'yacc_read.c']],
    extra_compile_args = compiler_args + ['/EHsc']
   )
]

setup(
  name = 'pylpsolve',
  ext_modules = cythonize(extensions),
)
```